# On what is τί contingent in Romans 8:31?

Tags: romans

> [Romans 8:31 NASB20] (31) What then shall we say to these things? If God [is] for us, who [is] against us?
>
> > [Romans 8:31 MGNT] (31) [τί](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1487&t=MGNT) οὖν ἐροῦμεν πρὸς ταῦτα εἰ ὁ θεὸς ὑπὲρ ἡμῶν τίς καθ᾽ ἡμῶν

Does Paul inform us of the condition he has in mind? Or does he leave it as an arbitrary condition?